# Move files to more than one folder using python

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I am trying to move files from one folder to a different folder and below is my code.

```
import os, shutil

path = "C:\\Users\\mypath"
moveto = "C:\\Users\\mypath1" # Moving to this folder after upload

files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
    src = path+f
    dst = moveto+f
    shutil.move(src,dst)
```

Is there a way I can move the same files to one additional folder as well so that I have two copies of the documents.

Comment: You can try to copy the entire folder using `shutil.copy(src, dst)` after your done with your loop. Otherwise, you can call the same `shutil.copy(src, dst)` inside the loop with your parameters and new folder location

Answer (score 0):

You could append all of your destination directories to a list, and then iterate through the list on each copy. This way you could have 1 -> N number of directories to copy to.

```
import os, shutil

path = "C:\\Users\\mypath"
moveToPaths = ["C:\\Users\\mypath1", "C:\\Users\\mypath2"] # Moving to this folder after upload

files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
    src = path+f
    for moveToPath in moveToPaths:
        dst = moveToPath+f
        shutil.copy(src,dst)
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help PrestonM... Still throws an error as file missing as the script in the second for loop has already moved the file and doesn't find it in the next iteration to move it to the second location. Perhaps a copy and move combination should be able to help.

Comment: Sorry for the error @ShashiShankarSingh. I modified it to perform a copy then delete.